# Align flalign and itemize to top in tabularx

Tags: math-mode, vertical-alignment, itemize, flalign

How do I align the `fbox` in the second column to the top so that the top rows of the two match?
I have tried with `minipage` and `makecell` and a ton of other things but I can't make it work. Any ideas?

PS! The `fbox`es will be removed later, they are just for illustration purposes DS

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}X|>{\centering\arraybackslash}X|}
    \hline
    \fbox{\parbox{0.9\linewidth}{
        \vspace{-4mm}
        \begin{flalign}
            &a + b  = 100 &&\\[2mm]
            &10c + e = 1000 &&\\[2mm]
            &a + b  = 100 &&\\[2mm]
            &c + e = 1000 &&
        \end{flalign}
        \vspace{-6mm}
    }}
    &
    \fbox{\parbox{0.9\linewidth}{
        \begin{itemize}[topsep=0pt, leftmargin=*]
            \item{B1}
        \end{itemize}
    }}\\
    \hline
  \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image: The problem]

Comment: Do you use `flalign` for anything else than alignment on the left side?

Comment: The `\parbox` command messes up the alignment here. If you use `\parbox[t]{...}` instead, bow boxes are to aligned. Since you mention the `\fbox` command just being for demonstration purposes, do you really need the `\parbox` commands in your actual document?

Comment: @Bernard Answer is no

Comment: @leandriis Works like a charm! Thanks! Works with both `fbox`es and `parbox`es. I want the parbox on the left side to add padding to the `flalign` and I use it in the other as well for consistency... you have a better idea? Feel free to answer the question and I shall accept the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean a vertical padding?

Comment: @Bernard no horizontal, otherwise the equation numbers and the formulas end up almost touching the cell borders

Comment: If I remove `fbox` and `\parbox`around the `flalig` environment, there is still some space between the vertical lines and the contents (6pt to be precise). If you want to change this value (for both columns, you can change the value of `\tabcolsep`, e.g. `\setlength{\tabcolsep}{10pt}` or if you only want to change this spacing for the left column, you cn use `@{\hspace{1cm}}` or any other value of your choise as in  `\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|@{\hspace{1cm}}>{\centering\arraybackslash}X@{\hspace{1cm}}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}X|}`.

Comment: @leandriis Sounds like good things I would want to try out but it doesn't allow me to have the `flalign` straight inside the `tabularx` without wrapping it in something (for example a `parbox`). I'm using Overleaf ...

Comment: Did you already try wrapping the `flalign` in a simple set of `{}`? If I remember correctly, this should work.

Comment: @leandriis Worked great with the additional `{}`, thanks! Feel free to answer this question in some way so that I can accept the answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probabl you're interested in something along the lines of the following:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\noindent
{
\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{0pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|@{\hspace{0.5cm}}>{\centering\arraybackslash}X@{\hspace{0.5cm}}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}X|}
    \hline
        {\begin{flalign}
            &a + b  = 100 &&\\
            &10c + e = 1000 &&\\
            &a + b  = 100 &&\\
            &c + e = 1000 &&
        \end{flalign}}
    &
        \begin{itemize}[topsep=0pt, leftmargin=*]
            \item{B1}
        \end{itemize}
    \\
    \hline
  \end{tabularx}
}
\end{document}
```